# How to copy input type password on click event?

Tags: php, jquery, copy, codeigniter-3

And this is how I'm trying to use the code:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" value='<?php echo $decrypt_value; ?>'  id="p2" name="">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2">
      <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" onclick="copyToClipboard('#p2')">Copy TEXT</button>
</div>
```

```
//use script for getting value from text box *
function copyToClipboard(element) {

              var $temp = $("<input>");
              $("body").append($temp);
              $temp.val($(element).val()).select();
             // alert($(element).val());
              document.execCommand("copy");
              $temp.remove();
}

//this is script using js
```

```js
            function copyToClipboard(element) {
              var $temp = $("<input>");
              $("body").append($temp);
              $temp.val($(element).val()).select();
             // alert($(element).val());
              document.execCommand("copy");
              $temp.remove();
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-6">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" value='<?php echo $decrypt_value; ?>'  id="p2" name="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
          <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" onclick="copyToClipboard('#p2')">Copy TEXT</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you specify what kind of problem you got with your code?

Answer (score 1):

Do  this shortcut method,just add id to your button

```
<button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" id="buttonCopyText">Copy TEXT</button>
$('#buttonCopyText').click(function () {
    var copyText = document.getElementById("p2");
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText.value);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I cant comment, this example, coppies text to clipboard

```js
function copyToClipboard(element) {
  var $temp = $("<input>");
  $("body").append($temp);
  $temp.val($(element).text()).select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  $temp.remove();
}
```

```css
body {
              background-color:#999999;
              font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
      }
p
{
  color:#000000;
  font-size:20px;
}

.textBox
{
  height:30px;
  width:300px;
}

button
{
  height:30px;
  width:150px;
  border-radius:8px;
  padding:10px;
  font-size:20px;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  height:52px;
  cursor:pointer;
  background-color:wheat;
}
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> 

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <p style="color:wheat;font-size:55px;text-align:center;">How to copy a TEXT to Clipboard on a Button-Click</p>

<center>
<p id="p1">Hello, I'm TEXT 1</p>
<p id="p2">Hi, I'm the 2nd TEXT</p><br/>

<button onclick="copyToClipboard('#p1')">Copy TEXT 1</button>
<button onclick="copyToClipboard('#p2')">Copy TEXT 2</button>
  
<br/><br/><input class="textBox" type="text" id="" placeholder="Dont belive me?..TEST it here..;)" />
</center>
```